# How to upload the content of a CSV file in my API using the header of the CSV as the request header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, csv

I know how to upload files by attaching the file to my request by using has_one_attached in the model.

But my goal is to upload the content of my CSV file and not the file itself. (the csv file also has a header I would like to use)
How do I setup my controller and model to enable this?

Some background info: I am using an ETL process to transform CSV files and would like to upload the content of these CSV files in my API. There will be many big files to upload and I would like to avoid making manual changes to the file.

A small example should suffice for this question though:

testfile1.csv

```
name;age;gender
max;23,m
lisa;12;f
gustavo;69;m
bernd;4;d
```

I saw this method for CSV files but I have no Idea how to implement it for my use

```
CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true) do |row|
  Model.create(name: row[0], age: row[1], gender: row[2])
end
```

Does the "Model.create" create a new model so I don't need a name, age and gender in my own model or how does it work?
Do I use it in a service?
Is params[:file] the way to access permitted attributes?

This is my first question here and I'm fairly inexperienced, I hope I included everything needed. Thank you in advance

Comment: For this to work: `Model.create(name: row[0], age: row[1], gender: row[2])` you need a model called Model with those attributes. `Model.create` it's just a generic example, if you have a model called Car then you'll do `Car.create` and you need the model to respond to those attributes. If you want to have flexible schemas for your models maybe you need a NoSQL database like MongoDB. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay. I am currently using postgresql. So I would need another create method in my "Car" model? Could you show me an example of how to implement the CSV.foreach... in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` method will let you iterate the csv file in question. Yes, `params[:file]` is letting you access the file (should be a permitted parameter on the controller if it's coming from a form). According to the example, objects in the `Model` class will have attributes - `name`, `age`, `gender`. `Model.create` will create an object with the supplied parameters and write it to the underlying database. `row` is an iteration variable here. `row` will iterate through all rows of the csv file. Only if `headers: true` is supplied (like here), the headers will be read.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm still not sure how to implement that in my controller. Could you give me an example for a create method?

Answer (score 0):

So after trying around a bit i found a solution for the ones who are interested, it might not be the cleanest but it seems to work for me. "Testfilemodel" is my other model where the content is saved. I think "filename" can be removed though.

```
class Api::FileuploadsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_fileupload, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
    require 'csv'
    def create
        @fileupload = csvmethod
    end

    private

    def file_params
        params.require(:fileupload).permit(:filename, :csvfile)
    end

    def csvmethod
        CSV.foreach(file_params[:csvfile].path, headers: true) do |row|
            Testfilemodel.create(name: row[0], age: row[1], gender: row[2])
        end
    end
    def set_fileupload
        @fileupload = Fileupload.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

In the "Testfilemodel" model I only have basic index and show methods to display the content.
Hope this helps if others have the same problem.